# doing authentication with other facebook account, facebook sdk, ios

Tags: ios, facebook

Im following the tutorial at [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/#step2) for how to do authentication

I can log in and log out successfully. However for the next time to log in, the facebookSDK automatically authenticates with the first facebook account.

Question

How can I log in with different facebook account after log out...

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are logged into facebook from the Safari Browser, try logging out the from safari first or use a UIWebView instead of Safari for authentication.